# How to design a web page for all resolution monitors in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have faced screen resolution problem for my asp.net web application. I have got solution from design experts. One of the solution is applying 100% width to all tables and divisions. I applied that 100% width to all tables and divisions. But still I am facing that problem. In Some system resolutions my web application works very well without any stretch. But in some other resolutions my web application is stretched. How to rectify that problem?

Comment: How do you design such a website on **any** platform?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the [Fluid 960 Grid](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/)?

It's based on the [960 Grid](http://960.gs/), though works fluid for all resolutions.

Once you have the `CSS` files in place you simply set the main `div` to one of the `container` classes, and then apply one of the `grid` classes to its children.

Something like:

```
 <!-- this will give a 12 piece container -->
 <div class="container_12">

    <!-- all grids used should add up to 12 -->

    <!-- I.E this 4 piece grid -->
    <div class="grid_4">some content</div>
    <!-- plus this 8 piece = 12 -->
    <div class="grid_8">some more content</div>
    <!-- then clear the grids floating -->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

Food for thought..

Answer (score 0):

Addressing this as an issue of CSS (since the issue is in no way specific to asp.net), the modern way to deal with this problem is to set the width (as well as the left and right margins and padding) of all your elements using percentages, as you've been instructed, and then use CSS media queries to change the styling of these elements depending on the width of the browser viewport.

These can go in the body of your stylesheet (alongside your normal style declarations) like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px){ /*rough viewport width for tablets */

/* style declarations go here, just 
 as they would in any other stylesheet, for example*/

#myDiv{ width:60%;}

}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){ /*rough viewport width for smartphones */


}
```

Or you can place your styles for that resolution in a totally separate stylesheet and call that file conditionally, like so :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
```